# bash treatment of multiple-column file

Tags: bash, multiple-columns

Dealing with processing of multi-column file consisted of many lines, I need to change a name of each line in the first column (notably remove the full path of processed file). Here is the format of the log:

```
/scratch_p/john/results_test_docking/7000/7000_12_lig_cne_767.dlg:   2 |    -10.50 |  10 |    -10.38 |  16 |################
/scratch_p/john/results_test_docking/7000/7000_08_lig_cne_767.dlg:   1 |    -10.41 |  11 |    -10.34 |  11 |###########
/scratch_p/john/results_test_docking/7000/7000_08_lig_cne_998.dlg:   1 |     -9.89 |   1 |     -9.34 |   7 |#######
/scratch_p/john/results_test_docking/7000/7000_06_lig_cne_998.dlg:   2 |     -9.64 |  12 |     -9.39 |   6 |######
/scratch_p/john/results_test_docking/7000/7000_04_lig_cne_900.dlg:   1 |     -9.62 |  12 |     -8.95 |  11 |###########
/scratch_p/john/results_test_docking/7000/7000_05_lig_cne_767.dlg:   1 |     -9.37 |  20 |     -9.13 |   5 |#####
/scratch_p/john/results_test_docking/7000/7000_08_lig_cne_331.dlg:   1 |     -9.31 |   8 |     -8.29 |   6 |######
/scratch_p/john/results_test_docking/7000/7000_12_lig_cne_900.dlg:   1 |     -9.16 |   8 |     -8.82 |   8 |########
/scratch_p/john/results_test_docking/7000/7000_08_lig_cne_818.dlg:   1 |     -9.12 |   3 |     -8.35 |   5 |#####
/scratch_p/john/results_test_docking/7000/7000_10_lig_cne_587.dlg:   1 |     -9.07 |  19 |     -8.50 |  10 |##########
/scratch_p/john/results_test_docking/7000/7000_09_lig_cne_515.dlg:   1 |     -9.02 |  12 |     -7.93 |   7 |#######
/scratch_p/john/results_test_docking/7000/7000_07_lig_cne_987.dlg:   1 |     -9.00 |  16 |     -8.77 |   8 |########
/scratch_p/john/results_test_docking/7000/7000_04_lig_cne_767.dlg:   2 |     -8.96 |   9 |     -8.88 |   8 |########
/scratch_p/john/results_test_docking/7000/7000_12_lig_cne_331.dlg:   1 |     -8.94 |  11 |     -8.54 |   9 |#########
/scratch_p/john/results_test_docking/7000/7000_10_lig_cne_331.dlg:   1 |     -8.90 |   1 |     -8.49 |   6 |######
/scratch_p/john/results_test_docking/7000/7000_10_lig_cne_767.dlg:   4 |     -8.87 |   4 |     -8.86 |  14 |##############
```

Here from each line I should to remove /scratch_p/john/results_test_docking/7000/ from the first column of each line (the pattern is usually shared between each line but in different logs it may be different...), so keeping only the name of .dlg file. Then I ought to remove the 2nd, 4th columns
The expected output for the above example should be:

```
7000_12_lig_cne_767.dlg:     -10.50 |      -10.38 |  16 |################
7000_08_lig_cne_767.dlg:     -10.41 |      -10.34 |  11 |###########
7000_08_lig_cne_998.dlg:      -9.89 |       -9.34 |   7 |#######
7000_06_lig_cne_998.dlg:      -9.64 |       -9.39 |   6 |######
7000_04_lig_cne_900.dlg:      -9.62 |       -8.95 |  11 |###########
7000_05_lig_cne_767.dlg:      -9.37 |       -9.13 |   5 |#####
7000_08_lig_cne_331.dlg:      -9.31 |       -8.29 |   6 |######
7000_12_lig_cne_900.dlg:      -9.16 |       -8.82 |   8 |########
7000_08_lig_cne_818.dlg:      -9.12 |       -8.35 |   5 |#####
7000_10_lig_cne_587.dlg:      -9.07 |       -8.50 |  10 |##########
7000_09_lig_cne_515.dlg:      -9.02 |       -7.93 |   7 |#######
7000_07_lig_cne_987.dlg:      -9.00 |       -8.77 |   8 |########
7000_04_lig_cne_767.dlg:      -8.96 |       -8.88 |   8 |########
7000_12_lig_cne_331.dlg:      -8.94 |       -8.54 |   9 |#########
7000_10_lig_cne_331.dlg:      -8.90 |       -8.49 |   6 |######
7000_10_lig_cne_767.dlg:      -8.87 |       -8.86 |  14 |##############
```

The only possible way to accomplish it is a manual edition in a text editor :-). Is it possible to do it rather using some bash utility?

Comment: Are the columns fixed width, always the same size?

Comment: Yes always the same format !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
cat test.txt |                         # get the file content
cut -d '|' -f 1,2,4- |                 # pick the columns we want
sed 's/^.*\/\([^/]*.dlg\):[^|]*/\1/'   # extract filename (ignoring path) and ignore first column after :
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for this kind solution! Could you tell me whether the SED expression would extract any kind of PATH information regardless of its name (keeping only the name of the DLG file) ? thanks !

Comment: I'd say "almost yes". It uses the `/` as a path separator and only takes the last element in that path, so it should only get the filename. However if you have filenames with a `/`, which would presumably show up escaped (e.g. `/path/to/filename\/with_slash.dlg`), then the script would probably fail on them.

Comment: Right, thank you again! So the only thing is to avoid occurence of "/" within the name of any folder present in the PATH and/or within the name of the filename..

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk:

```sh
gawk '
  BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS = "66 6 12 6 12 6 *" }
  {
     sub(/.*\//, "", $1)
     print $1 $3 $5 $6 $7
  }
' file
```

This can be simplified a bit, since you're keeping everything after column 4:

```sh
gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS="66 6 12 6 *" '{sub(/.*\//, "", $1); print $1 $3 $5}' file
# ....................1.2..3.4.5
```